# Accumulator of value in thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I use spring boot 2 and thymeleaf

In a class name **SamplesTestResult**

```
private Double compression;
private Double flexion;
```

I have a list of **SamplesTestResult**

```
<div th:each="testResult: ${samplesTestResult}" th:remove="tag">         
    <table>
        <tr th:if="{testResult.compression!=null}">
            <td th:text=" 'Compression ' +  $ {}"></td><td th:text="'Requirement' + ${testResult.compression}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr th:if="{testResult.flexion!=null}">
            <td th:text=" 'Flexion ' +  $ {}"></td><td th:text=" 'Requirement' + ${testResult.flexion}"></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
</div>
```

So the result is

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Compression 12</td>
        <td>Flexion 14</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Compression 22</td>
        <td>Flexion 17</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I search to get

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Compression 12, 22</td>
        <td>Flexion 14, 17</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I think to get that, I would need to create a  kind a variable to stock value?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  What is your search query and where is your search code?  Are you querying using a range?

Comment: question is about displaying data with the data strucutre.. query have nothing to do...

Comment: Oh, so you're writing that you looked for a solution to give you the bottom example.   If I understand correctly, you'd just print the value of the requirement.  You can hardcode it or store it as a property in a bean if you see it changing.  For example, you can add a property called `compressionRequirement` and update that accordingly.  Note that you may also have a typo in `sampletTestResult`.